# Missing Snippet Highlighting for feed content

Tags: google-search-appliance

Feed content is missing snippet highlighting. It highlights the title fine.

Here is an example record pulled from the submitted feed,

```
<record url="http://my.example.com/1" mimetype="text/html" displayurl="http://my.example.com/1" action="add">
  <metadata>
    <meta name="CategoryId" content="25" />
    <meta name="CommentCount" content="0" />
    <meta name="Dimension" content="2d" />
    <meta name="PublishDate" content="2011/11/17 10:26 AM" />
    <meta name="ItemCategory" content="multimedia" />
    <meta name="SuperType" content="Videos" />
  </metadata>
  <content><![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>blah blah blah blah</title><meta name="title" content="yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada yada" /><meta name="description" content="hey hey hey hey hey what yes no hello goodbye" /></head></html>]]></content>
</record>
```

Answer (score 1):

Snippet highlighting is missing because you do not have any body content in your submitted feed.
From your sample record, it is clear that you are just indexing meta information. You have to place your content inside `<body> your content</body>` tag.You can check you crawl diagnostics (Status and Reports >Crawl Diagnostics for GSA Version 7.0) to understand what content have been indexed by GSA. For your record it must be empty.

Regards,

Mohan